# Uploading multiple images onto a panel in Java

Tags: java, image, upload

I'm trying to upload multiple images onto a panel but I don't just know how to do this. I can upload a single image but not more than one at a time. Actually I need this knowledge to make a simple card game I recently designed look more real.

Can anyone help me out.

Comment: Do you mean a JPanel? Or is this a web application?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to set a layout, add a layout manager, and slot in some panels inside your panel.

That way you can add the images to each of the sub-panels, and arrange them according to the layout manager.